# Trying to get Scala imports with hiding clause and catch-all

Tags: scala, import

Okay, so I have written the below Scala code to explore Scala imports. My objective to import all members of object Vegetables except Asparagus. I understand that the way to do this is to write the following clause (after doing com.att.scala.Vegetables)

```
  **import Vegetables.{Asparagus=>_,_}**
```

Since my purpose is to confirm the intentions of the above clause I set out to ask the REPL to return Asparagus.name. In my mind I expected the REPL to say something like 
**"Hey you asked me not to import Asparagus with your renaming clause, so I have no Asparagus to give you"**

Instead the REPL returns 
     **res5: java.lang.String = Asparagus**

Of course when I type in JapaneseSpinach.color it works as expected and returns
     **res7: java.awt.Color = java.awt.Color[r=0,g=255,b=0]**

It is apparent to me, that I am missing something here. My goal is to understand the way the hiding clause works and to confirm that the hiding clause does indeed hide a member (hiding to my mind means that the member is actually not available..)

My code is below:

```
   package com.att.scala

   import java.awt.Color
   trait Vegetable {
     val name: String
    val color: Color
  }

 object Vegetables {
  object Asparagus extends Vegetable { 
    val name = "Asparagus"
    val color = Color.GREEN  
  } 

object Carrot extends Vegetable { 
   val name = "Carrot"
   val color = Color.ORANGE 
}

object Parsnip extends Vegetable { 
  val name = "Parsnip"
  val color = Color.ORANGE
}

object JapaneseSpinach {
  val name = "Komatsuna"
  val color = Color.GREEN
 }
 val veggiePlatter = List(Asparagus, Carrot)

def showColor(veggie: Vegetable) {
  println("Entered showColor")
  import veggie._
  println("Veggie name is " + name)
}

   def test() {
     println("entered test")
   }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but `import Vegetables.{Asparagus=>,}`, IMO is illegal syntax. You should write `import Vegetables.{Asparagus => _, _}`

Comment: My bad. That was an unintended, careless error, but thanks for pointing it out. But I did in fact have:                         import Vegetables. {Asparagus=>_,_}

Answer (score 0):

First thanks to om-nom-nom also.
Earlier I was using the import clause like below:
      **import Vegetables.{Asparagus=>*,*}**
Instead of the REPL saying something like "**Hey you asked me not to import Asparagus with your renaming clause, so I have no Asparagus to give you**" 
it was still returning Asparagus.name and Asparagus.color. (when I typed in "import Asparagus.name" as a test)

This was when I realized I was missing something. The result is counter intuitive. Asparagus was supposed to be not visible. On taking a closer look I found I had goofed up in the following way:

I had forgotten to factor in the fact that earlier I had already imported object Vegetable using the following statement:
       import com.att.scala.Vegetable.

The above statement must have brought in **all** members of Vegetable into the scope.
Later I applied the renaming and catch-all clause and it did not work because of the first import. So I decided to try on a fresh slate again.

I restarted Eclipse, fired up Eclipse and issued the following commands: This time I did it as below:

```
     **import com.att.scala.Vegetables.{Asparagus=>_,_}**

       **Asparagus.name**
```

The REPL came right back with the following response:

```
         **<console>:11: error: not found: value Asparagus
          Asparagus.name
          ^**
```

This was my intended result.